# How do I make filemaker recognize records from an imported file

Tags: filemaker

I imported an excel list of student names and ID's. The teachers job is to either scan or manually enter student ID's and when done so, filemaker will automatically add the student name from the excel list. If the teacher mistyped the student ID, then the name would not show because it is not in the excel list. How do I make filemaker tell the user to stop and retype the student ID not allowing the teacher/user to add anymore students until they fix the current mistyped ID?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do I make filemaker tell the user to stop and retype the student
>   ID not allowing the teacher/user to add anymore students until they
>   fix the current mistyped ID?

You can (and should)  *validate* the field. The validation here could be as `Member of value list: [StudentIDs]`, where "StudentIDs" would be a value list using values from the StudentID field in the imported table.

**Note**: Filemaker's validation error messages can be somewhat intimidating to the users, so you may consider adding a script triggered OnObjectValidate to run a "pre-validation" check and guide the user in case of an invalid entry, for example:

```
If [ IsEmpty ( FilterValues ( Attendance::StudentID ; ValueListItems ( Get (FileName) ; "StudentIDs" ) ) ) ] 
    Show Custom Dialog [ Message: "There is no student with this ID. Please correct your entry."; Buttons: “OK” ] 
    Exit Script [ Result: 0 ] 
End If
```

Comment: @mochael.hor257k Can you write me a sample script on how I can create that validation? I'm fairly new to filemaker